# How to memoize a matrix in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, matrix

I'm currently building a pathfinding visualizer in react, this is my code so far:

```
const COLUMNS = 45;
const ROWS = 15;

const Grid = () => {

    const [nodesMatrix, setNodesMatrix] = useState([]);
    const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(5);

    const [startNodeRow, setStartNodeRow] = useState(0);
    const [startNodeCol, setStartNodeCol] = useState(0);
    const [endNodeRow, setEndNodeRow] = useState(4);
    const [endNodeCol, setEndNodeCol] = useState(4);


    //Initializes Grid
    useEffect(() => {
        const cells = [];
            for (let row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
                const currentRow = [];
                for (let col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
                    currentRow.push({
                        row,
                        col,
                        isStart: row === startNodeRow && col === startNodeCol,
                        isEnd: row === endNodeRow && col === endNodeCol,
                        distance: Infinity,
                        visited: false,
                        previousNode: null
                    });
                };
                cells.push(currentRow);
            };
            
            setNodesMatrix(cells);
    }, [startNodeRow, startNodeCol, endNodeRow, endNodeCol]);

    const updateNodes = (isStart, newRow, newCol) => {
        clearAllNodesStyles();

        if (isStart) {
            setStartNodeRow(newRow);
            setStartNodeCol(newCol);
        } else {
            setEndNodeRow(newRow);
            setEndNodeCol(newCol);
        }
    };


    return (
        <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
            <div className="flex flex-col self-center">
                {nodesMatrix.map((row, rowIndex) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={rowIndex} className='flex'>
                            {row.map((node, index) => {

                                const { row, col, isStart, isEnd } = node;

                                return <Node
                                    key={index}
                                    row={row}
                                    col={col}
                                    isStart={isStart}
                                    isEnd={isEnd}
                                    updateNodes={updateNodes} />
                            })}
                        </div>
                    )
                })
                }

                <button
                    onClick={() => visualizeDijkstra(nodesMatrix, { startNodeRow, startNodeCol, endNodeRow, endNodeCol, speed })}
                    className="h-20 w-full text-white hover:bg-blue-800 bg-blue-700 place-self-end">
                    Search Path
                </button>
            </div>
        </DndProvider>
    )

};
```

The problem is that this implementation is pretty slow. Whenever I change either the `start` or `end` nodes position it takes about a second/second & half to update because it has to create the matrix every single time. Not only this is undesirable but it's also not the behavior I want: Currently it'll only update once you drop the dragged node into another position, but my intent is that the user is able to see how the selected node is being updated as they drag it over the grid (much like it works on this project: https://pathfindout.com/ ). My first thought was to memoize or somehow cache the initial matrix. I've looked into other people repos but most of them are using old versions of react and I haven't been able to pull this off properly, it still has pretty bad performance or presents bugs whenever I try to update the `start`/`end` nodes. And this is only with two nodes, I plan on adding walls and maze generation which means more updates.

After a few days of trying to solve this, this was my latest attemp:

```
...
    const [nodesMatrix, setNodesMatrix] = useState([]);
    const [resetMatrix, setResetMatrix] = useState([]);
...

useEffect(() => {
        const cells = [];
            for (let row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
                const currentRow = [];
                for (let col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
                    currentRow.push({
                        row,
                        col,
                        isStart: row === startNodeRow && col === startNodeCol,
                        isEnd: row === endNodeRow && col === endNodeCol,
                        distance: Infinity,
                        visited: false,
                        previousNode: null
                    });
                };
                cells.push(currentRow);
            };

            setNodesMatrix(cells);
            setResetMatrix(cells);
    }, []);

 const updateNodes = (isStart, newRow, newCol) => {
        clearAllNodesStyles();

        if (isStart) {
            setNodesMatrix(resetMatrix);
            nodesMatrix[startNodeRow][startNodeCol].isStart = false;
            nodesMatrix[newRow][newCol].isStart = true;
            setStartNodeRow(newRow);
            setStartNodeCol(newCol);
        } else {
            setNodesMatrix(resetMatrix);
            nodesMatrix[endNodeRow][endNodeCol].isEnd = false;
            nodesMatrix[newRow][newCol].isEnd = true;
            setEndNodeRow(newRow);
            setEndNodeCol(newCol);
        }
    };
...
```

Which obviously doesn't really work, nor solves the underlying issues. I don't really know if the `dnd-react` library is causing some sort of performance drawback, but I'm leaning towards my bad logic. Is there a way to memoize or update my matrix more efficiently?

Comment: Does wrapping the `Node` component in [`memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) help?

Comment: Also wrap the `updateNodes` function with [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback). This should be combined with my previous comment (doing one or the other is unlikely to work).

Comment: @Wing I was using memo on the ```Node``` component but didn't think about the useCallback implementation! I added that and it seems to be running *far* more smoothly. I'll try to add the walls and the maze generation to see how it holds up!